# Cannot find column 2

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

```
private void btnmap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{               
   XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();                
   con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
   ds = new DataSet();
   con.ConnectionString = @"Server=MDS-SW02; User ID=sa; Pwd=Admin2011;Initial Catalog=xml;";
   con.Open();
   MessageBox.Show("Database Connected");                
   String sql = "select Pdf_tag,Styles from Xml_Tags";              
   com = new SqlCommand(sql);           
   da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql,con);             
   da.Fill(ds, "xml");                
   maxrows = ds.Tables["xml"].Rows.Count;
   StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(file,Encoding.Default,true);

   do
   {                                           
      string line = objReader.ReadLine();
      string st1 = ">";
      string st2 = "</";
      int end = line.IndexOf(st2);
      if (end != -1 && end > 1)
      {
         st = line.IndexOf(st1);
         en = line.IndexOf(st2);
         int v = en - st;
         sub = line.Substring(st + 1, v - 1);                            
         rchtext.Text = rchtext.Text + sub + "\r\n"; 
      }                     
      for (int i = 0; i < maxrows; i++)
      {
          dRow = ds.Tables["xml"].Rows[i];
          if(dRow[0].ToString ()==line)
          {
              //XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
              XmlNode docNode = xmldoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
              xmldoc.AppendChild(docNode);
              XmlNode xmlnode,xmlroot;

              String sqll = "select Dtd_Tag from Xml_Tags where Mapped_Tags_Attributes.Pdf_Tag=Xml_Tags.Pdf_Tag";
              SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sqll);
              SqlDataAdapter daa = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqll, con);
              daa.Fill(ds1, "xml");
              dRow1 = ds1.Tables["xml"].Rows[i];

              string name = XmlConvert.EncodeName(dRow1.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString());
              xmlnode = xmldoc.CreateElement(name);

              XmlNode Doc = xmldoc.CreateDocumentType(name, null, "E:\\Rachana_mds\\proj\\pdfextraction\\docbook.dtd", null);
              xmldoc.AppendChild(Doc);

              xmlroot = xmldoc.CreateElement(dRow1.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString());
              xmldoc.AppendChild(xmlroot);             

              String sqlll = "select Dtd_Attribute_Name from Mapped_Tags_Attributes where Mapped_Tags_Attributes.Pdf_Tag=Xml_Tags.Pdf_Tag";
              SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlll);
              SqlDataAdapter dt = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlll,con);
              dt.Fill(ds2, "xml");
              dRow2 = ds2.Tables["xml"].Rows[i];

              xmlroot = xmldoc.CreateElement(name);
              xmldoc.AppendChild(xmlroot);
              XmlAttribute xmlatt = xmldoc.CreateAttribute(dRow2.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString());                                              
              xmlroot.AppendChild(xmlnode);
              xmlnode.InnerText=sub;                       
            }                                                                
            while (objReader.Peek() != -1);
            //string filename = @"E:" + DateTime.Now.Day + DateTime.Now.Month + DateTime.Now.Minute + ".xml";
            string filename = @"E:\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")+".xml";
            xmldoc.Save(filename); 
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
            con.Close();                                  
}
```

Comment: Is there a question that goes with that?

Comment: What is this meant for where you are getting error

Comment: i hav declared ds1 and ds2 globally...i need to get element from one table and attribute from other table to create xml..

Answer (score 3):

Ah, now that you've told us the line with the error (comments), the problem is obvious:

```
dRow = ds.Tables["xml"].Rows[i];
if(dRow[i].ToString ()==line) {...}
```

`dRow` is a row; unless your data is pure square, you probably intended to access the first column for each row:

```
dRow = ds.Tables["xml"].Rows[i];
if(dRow[0].ToString ()==line) {...}
```

Comment: i am getting error in this line..if(dRow[i].ToString ()==line)

Comment: i am trying to get DTD tags stored in database to replace the tags in pdf converted text file to create xml

Comment: i dint get u sir.. wat do u mean by updating? wat should i update?

Comment: @rachana I mean you should refresh your browser and see the update I just made to my answer

Comment: no sir.. any other solution do u hav?

Comment: Instead of `dRow[i].ToString()==line ` use `dRow[0].ToString ()==line` i.e the update

Comment: now m getting other error... Invalid XML document, The document does not have a root element..error line is xmldoc.Save(filename);.. pls check wat is wrong..

Comment: @rachana your code doesn't show that line, so *how would I know*? It looks like you have moved `xmldoc` somewhere higher, so I can't see how it is scoped, or what happens when the line isn't a match. Honestly, you need to pick up some elementary step-through debugging experience here...

Comment: But in the provided code you did not mention that right

Comment: sorry sir.. i hav edited code now... its at the down... pls check now

Comment: I am confused from your code Are you creating a new file or you are getting the existed one. As per your code there will be no file present

Comment: ya ya.. m creating a new file...

Comment: @rachana - it is not clear what file(s) you intended to create, and frankly this is an unrelated question... you are appending to `xmldoc` (as a root node) many times in the code. I have ***no clue*** what you are trying to construct here.

Comment: Try this `@"E:\"` instead of `@"E:"`

Comment: And you are writing such a long `datetime` when you have an option as `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")`

Comment: m trying to construct xml for the elements and attributes present in the database..those two are stored in different table

Comment: sir i hav changed code now... pls go through it once and check wats wrong... i want to replace tags in text file from tags stored in database to create xml..

Comment: oops This may questions in one question first of all let us know clearly what you exactly trying to do by updating your question

Comment: i want to create xml file by retreiving elements and attributes from database and replacing thise tags in text file (pdf converted text file) this project is about pdf converted text file to xml file..

Comment: i am waiting for ur replay sir..

Comment: @rachana and I'm still waiting for you to indicate where `xmldoc` is initialized; and to answer the question about what is going to happen when `Row[0].ToString ()==line` is not true (so no elements are appended)

Comment: ya sir... xmldoc is initialised at the top.. if Row[0].ToString ()==line that condition is not true then element is not appended... how to to write that.. pls mention code..

Comment: @rachana - right; 2 problems; first, you are sharing the document between all the items in the loop. Move the doc declaration / etc **inside** the loop. Second; if the condition is false, and nothing is appended, then ***the document is empty***; that is not valid for xml - so simply: don't try and save it. Either: add the root element *even if it isn't a match*, or: don't try to save an empty document